# Unable to send email through nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm developing node.js application in localhost. In this I'm trying to send mail using nodemailer.

Here is the code to used to send mail:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
module.exports = {
sendMail : function( message, htmlMessage, subject, email ) {
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( {
service : 'gmail',
host : 'smtp.gmail.com',
auth : {
user : 'username',
pass : 'password'
            },
tls: {
rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        });
// setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
from : 'sender mail id', // sender address
to : email, // list of receivers
subject : subject, // Subject line
text : message, // plain text body
html : htmlMessage // html body
        };
// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail( mailOptions, (error, info) => {
if (error) {
return console.log(error);
            }
console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
        });
    }
};
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 74.125.130.108:587

at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {

errno: -4039,

code: 'ESOCKET',

syscall: 'connect',

address: '74.125.130.108',

port: 587,

command: 'CONN'

}
```

Kindly someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is most commonly a firewall issue where you can't make connections to port 587. Check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

If your firewall is already turned off, you should make these changes.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
module.exports = {
sendMail : function( message, htmlMessage, subject, email ) {
                     const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                                         service : 'gmail',
                                         auth : {
                                                 user : 'username',
                                                 pass : 'password'
                                                }
                                        });
// setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
            from : 'xyz@gmail.com', // sender address
            to : email, // list of receivers
            subject : subject, // Subject line
            text : message, // plain text body
        };
// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail( mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }
            console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
            console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
        });
    }
};
```

Once you setup, open the link https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps and turn 'ON' Allow less secure apps: ON. And then check by running your node server.

Comment: I tried making changes as mentioned but still I'm getting connection timedout error as I mentioned above.

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings? Majority of times the issue is related to that.

Comment: Yes checked the firewall settings. I have turned off firewall.